# How to define the size of paragraph indent

Tags: indentation

How do I get this indentation?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Which indention do you want, the one in front of `As literaturas` or `Doencas`?

Comment: This seems to be a quote.  While having a different scheme of indentation compared to your picture, I believe the `\begin{quote} ... \end{quote}` environment suits your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion the other answers are bad, because they entirely disregard the *semantics* of having a quote and focus entirely on the visual markup.  However, if you want to typeset a quote in LaTeX, I recommend you use the `\begin{quote} ... \end{quote}` environment.

If you need more flexibility or you want to annotate your quotes with quotation marks and literature citations, check the [`csquotes`](https://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\blindtext
\begin{quote}
  \blindtext
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but an answer is bad when to when it does not respond to what is asked , not when it does not respond to what  possibly should  be asked `:)`

Comment: @Fran The answer being bad *in my opinion* is quite different from it being *objectively* bad, which it isn't.  If it was, I would have downvoted.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parskip1em
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

{\parindent5em\lipsum[2]}
{\parindent5em\hangindent5em\lipsum[2]}
{\parindent1em\hangindent3em\hangafter4\lipsum[2]}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Please use the `parskip` package rather than setting `\parskip` manually.  Setting it manually will likely screw up all your lists and headings too.

Comment: @HenriMenke I know, but for a example  that show how work `\parindent`, seem to me  less demonstrative start with a package that hiddenly change the paragraph  indentation  and I used to not load packages that are not needed really as in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You have two packages which can do that:

- `hanging` which defines a `\hangpara` command and a `hangparas` environment (for all paragraphs inside the environment). Both take two arguments: the hanging  length and the number of untouched lines.
- `quoting`, which lets you define a customisable quotation environment: inparticular, you can set the left and right margins, and vertical skip w.r.t. the surrounding text.

Demo:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{quoting} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlength{\myhangindent}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\setlength{\myhangindent}{3cm }

\hangpara{\myhangindent}{0}%
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]

\begin{quoting}[leftmargin=3cm, rightmargin=0pt, vskip=0pt]
  \lipsum[4]
\end{quoting}

\begin{hangparas}{\myhangindent}{1}%
\lipsum[5-8]
\end{hangparas}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I upvote all your answer to everybody. All users are excellent.